# Get-Net* PowerShell cmdlets failing with Invalid class

Tags: windows-10, powershell

How can I troubleshoot and fix `Get-Net*` PowerShell cmdlets? All of the following are failing with `Invalid class`. I'm using Windows 10, version 1511 and do not have the option to upgrade to 1607 at this point.

First PowerShell version:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10586  672
```

Errors:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetAdapter
Get-NetAdapter : Invalid class
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetAdapter
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (MSFT_NetAdapter:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetAdapter) [Get-NetAdapter], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Get-NetAdapter

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetIPAddress
Get-NetIPAddress : Invalid class
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetIPAddress
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (MSFT_NetIPAddress:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPAddress) [Get-NetIPAddress], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Get-NetIPAddress

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo
Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo : Invalid class
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (MSFT_NetAdapterHardwareInfoSettingData:ROOT/StandardCi...InfoSettingData
   ) [Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetAdapterBinding
Get-NetAdapterBinding : Invalid class
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetAdapterBinding
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (MSFT_NetAdapterBindingSettingData:ROOT/StandardCi...dingSettingData) [Ge
   t-NetAdapterBinding], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Get-NetAdapterBinding

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetAdapterStatistics -Name "Wi-Fi"
Get-NetAdapterStatistics : Invalid class
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetAdapterStatistics -Name "Wi-Fi"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (MSFT_NetAdapterStatisticsSettingData:ROOT/StandardCi...ticsSettingData)
   [Get-NetAdapterStatistics], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Get-NetAdapterStatistics

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetAdapterStatistics -Name "Ethernet"
Get-NetAdapterStatistics : Invalid class
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetAdapterStatistics -Name "Ethernet"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (MSFT_NetAdapterStatisticsSettingData:ROOT/StandardCi...ticsSettingData)
   [Get-NetAdapterStatistics], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Get-NetAdapterStatistics
```

I'm trying to use Docker for Windows 10 (which used to work) but the PowerShell failures are causing Docker to not start ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/260)). The errors are occurring on my host, not inside Docker containers. For the sake of this question you should ignore the Docker details, it is just that I cannot use Docker due to this problem.

Comment: Version 1511 or 1607?  I have no problems running Docker on Windows 10.  Update your question to include this information.

Comment: Is that on your host? Within the container? What's running in the Container? What PowerShell versoin are you using (Check `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`)?

Comment: Added all those details.

Comment: Yeah, are you just saying to `choco install powershell`? Would upgrading/repairing PowerShell outside of choco be possible?

Comment: @bbodenmiller - [Windows Management Framework 5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395) the command I suggested likely won't work for Windows 10.  You can use the PackageManagement (aka OneGet) to download Powershell 5.0.10586.201 after you add Chocolatey as a source.  I can't find WMF in the windows features which seems odd

Comment: It looks like I'm already using a newer version of PowerShell than that though.

Comment: @bbodenmiller - Its broken though, so what do you have to lose, by replacing it? The best solution would be to upgrade to 1607 since that would solve the problem.

Comment: If you run `Get-Module`, does it list NetAdapter?

Comment: @Ramhound so how do I use OneGet to download and install Powershell 5.0.10586.201 then? As mentioned upgrading to 1607 is not an option.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - Based on the fact, the Docker bug report was submitted by the author, it does not.  All the commands don't exist for the author and the other user in the bug report.  Of course its not listed for me and the NetAdapter cmdlets work just fine for me.

Comment: @bbodenmiller - After you add chocolatey as a Package Provider, you can install it with the `Get-Package` cmdlet.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 `Get-Module` just lists `Script`. Or are you talking about in `ExportedCommands` in `Get-Module`?

Comment: "Get-Module just lists Script" - That's a problem it should also list `Microsoft.Powershell.Managerment`, `Microsoft.Powershell.Utility`, and `PSReadLine`  You clearly don't have a Windows Feature installed that you need to use the cmdlet your trying to use.  "As mentioned upgrading to 1607 is not an option." - Everything is an option if its the only solution to a problem.

Comment: If it is against company policy, then it is not an option even if it is a fix.

Comment: @bbodenmiller have your it department reimage the machine, that's the only other way, I know will solve the problem

Comment: The good 'ol just reimage it - thanks but I'll keep trying other methods for now.

Answer (score 21):

Thanks to a thread on the [Microsoft TechNet Forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8ed26d46-9994-4052-a307-5b071805aea8/wmi-corrupt-how-to-reinstallrepair), we can see that the WMI repository is corrupted and can be fixed as follows:

1. Disable and stop the WMI service

> ```
> sc config winmgmt start= disabled
> net stop winmgmt
> ```

2. Run the following commands

> ```
>  Winmgmt /salvagerepository %windir%\System32\wbem
>  Winmgmt /resetrepository %windir%\System32\wbem
> ```

4. Re-enable the WMI service and reboot

> ```
>  sc config winmgmt start= auto
> ```

If the problem remains, then try the following steps to rebuild the repository:

1. Disable and stop the WMI service

> ```
>  sc config winmgmt start= disabled     (note that there is a blank between '=' and 'disabled')
>  net stop winmgmt
> ```

2. Rename the repository folder (located at `%windir%\System32\wbem\repository`) to `repository.old`
3. Re-enable the WMI service

> sc config winmgmt start= auto

4. Reboot the machine.

If the above doesn't work try `chkdsk`, [`sfc`](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-sfc-command-run-windows-10-a.html), and [`dism`](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html#option1s6). Additionally you can try a [Windows Repair Install](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Answer (score 1):

Some machines doesnt understand sc command. So try `sc.exe` instead of `sc` command.

```
sc.exe config winmgmt start= disabled
```